# SAS Proc Datasets - Change dataset name using macro variable

Tags: sas

I want to change dataset names in SAS using concatenated macro variables. Using the example code below I get an error. Is my syntax wrong or is it not possible to use a concatenating function in this way?

**Code:**

```
 %let term=201610;
 %let emp='bob';

 Proc Datasets library=work;
 change testset = cat(&emp,&term);
 run;
```

**Errors Received:**

ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: ALTER, MEMTYPE, MT, MTYPE, PROTECT, PW, READ, WRITE.

ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to concatenate macro variables, it's like a find and replace text. 
Because you have quotes right now this is what would happen:

```
 change testset = cat('bob', 201610)
```

But the CAT function is not valid there. You could technically use %SYSFUNC() to use the CAT function but there's an easier way.

```
 %let term=201610;
 %let emp='bob';

 Proc Datasets library=work;
 change testset = &emp&term.;
 run;quit;
```

Note that PROC DATASETS requires a QUIT to terminate.

Comment: The quotes around 'bob' need removing as well

Comment: Thanks, fixed it.